# Как написать условия клика на ТО или на ЭТО

Tags: jquery

Не знаю как сделать условие клика на ТО или на ЭТО, пока написал это, но не работает.

```
$(document).on("click", ".mobile-menu" || ".mobile-menu-close", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".mobile-menu-container").toggleClass("loaded");
  $(".mobile-menu").fadeToggle();
  $(".mobile-menu-close").toggleClass("show");
  $(".mobile-menu-overlay").fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перечислите через запятую нужные вам селекторы.

```
$(document).on("click", ".mobile-menu, .mobile-menu-close", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".mobile-menu-container").toggleClass("loaded");
    $(".mobile-menu").fadeToggle();
    $(".mobile-menu-close").toggleClass("show");
    $(".mobile-menu-overlay").fadeToggle();
});
```